# YUI skinning scrollbar used in container

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml, yui

How can I implement custom-looking scrollbars in YUI containers?

Comment: In short, you can't do this in a cross-browser (or cross-platform for that matter) way, is that a concern at all?

Comment: May be at least for those browsers where I can?

Comment: Why do you want to do this would be my next question...stop and think, maybe there's a reason most browsers don't allow this.  Personally I'd leave your site the instant it opened, you shouldn't be *trying* to change fundamental features of the browser.  What's next, styling my address bar? :)

Answer (score 0):

Using YUI3, you can change the scroll bars of an internal frame. If you ment the external scroll bars of the actual browser -- just drop the idea. It is not worth any headache. Too many browsers simply won't let you.

Here is example of an internal setup skinned in YUI 3.4

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #video-playlist-scroll-bar-container{text-align:right}
    #video-playlist-scroll-bar{position:relative;width:14px;border:1px solid #e0e0e0;height:379px;margin:0 auto}
    #drag-handle-container-wrap{position:relative;top:17px;bottom:17px;left:0;width:14px;height:345px}
    #drag-handle-container-wrap .yui3-slider-content{position:absolute;top:0;left:0}
    #drag-handle-draggable{position:absolute;left:0;background-color:#eaeaea;text-align:center;cursor:move;width:14px}
    #drag-handle-up,#drag-handle-down{position:absolute;display:block;width:14px;height:16px;cursor:pointer}
    #drag-handle-up{top:0;left:0}
    #drag-handle-down{bottom:0;left:0}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="yui3-u-1-12" id="video-playlist-scroll-bar-container">
  <div id="video-playlist-scroll-bar">
    <div id="drag-handle-up"><img src="/assets/images/rebrand/drag-arrow-top.gif"></div>
    <div id="drag-handle-container-wrap">
    <span class="yui3-widget yui3-sliderbase yui3-slider" style=""><span class="yui3-slider-content yui3-slider-y"><div id="drag-handle-container" style="height: 345px; ">
      <div id="drag-handle-draggable" class="yui3-dd-draggable" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; ">
          <img src="/assets/images/rebrand/drag-handle.gif" width="9" height="100">
        </div></div></span></span></div>
    <div id="drag-handle-down"><img src="/assets/images/rebrand/drag-arrow-bottom.gif"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

YUI:

```
YUI().use("base","node",'slider',function(Y){
  var CLICK = "click",
      ID = "#",
      _scrollingBuffer = 75,
      _maxScrollRegion = 0;

  // Slider
  var _tmp = Y.one(ID+'playlist-container'+" .video-playlist-item"),
      _nodeBuffer = Y.one(ID+'playlist-container').get('children').slice(-5),
      _bufferFunction = function() {
        var _height = 0;
        _nodeBuffer.each(function(i) {
          _height = _height + i.get('region').height;
        });
        return _height;
      },
      _buffer = _bufferFunction(),
      _maxScrollRegion = Y.one(ID+'playlist-container').get("region").height - _buffer;

  var listScroll = new Y.Slider({
      axis  : 'y',
      min   : 0, // reverse min and max to make the top
      max   : _maxScrollRegion,
      value : 0,
      length: '345px'
  });
  listScroll.renderRail = function () {
      return Y.one( "#drag-handle-container" );
  };
  listScroll.renderThumb = function () {
      return this.rail.one( "#drag-handle-draggable" );
  };

  listScroll.render( "#drag-handle-container-wrap" );

  listScroll.on('valueChange', Y.bind(function (e) {
    //scroll something?
  }));

  Y.one("#drag-handle-up").on(CLICK, Y.bind(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (listScroll.get('value') >= _scrollingBuffer) {
      listScroll.setValue(listScroll.get('value') - _scrollingBuffer);
    } else {
      listScroll.setValue(0);
    }
  }));
  Y.one("#drag-handle-down").on(CLICK, Y.bind(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (listScroll.get('value') <= Math.round(_maxScrollRegion - _scrollingBuffer)) {
        listScroll.setValue(listScroll.get('value') + _scrollingBuffer);
      } else {
        listScroll.setValue(_maxScrollRegion);
    }
  }));
});
```

Note, this is pretty much a copy/paste from a project of mine -- with a quick removal of any identifiers. It may not work as a copy/paste .. but you'll get the jist.

Final product:
[image: YUI3 Slider]

You could go even further by not using a "overflow: auto;" CSS and use the YUI 3 ScrollView along with it. I use the Paged version on YUI myself. It is easy enough to do a up & down by page & percentages.

Hopefully this is what you were looking for, not the browser's scroll bar.